# Redis keeps calling out to localhost:6379 even though deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, redis, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails app deployed to Heroku and I cant for the life of me figure out why it keeps wanting to deploy to the local. I do not even have localhost:6379 anywhere in my code for the front end (react native) or the back end which is my Rails API.

This is the error I get any time I have a new broadcast:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 111ms (ActiveRecord: 47.1ms)
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
```

Application.yaml:

```
`gmail_username: "<email_address>"
gmail_password: "<password>"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY: "<access_key>"
AWS_SECRET_KEY: "<secret_key>"
AWS_BUCKET: "<my_s3_app_bucket>"
REDIS_URL: "<redis_url>"`
```

Cable.yaml

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <long_url_address>
  host: <host_from_url>
  port: <port_from_url>
  password: <password_from_url>
```

Production.rb:

```
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ["https://lynx-v1.herokuapp.com/"]
  config.action_cable.url = "wss://lynx-v1.herokuapp.com/cable"
  config.web_socket_server_url = "wss://lynx-v1.herokuapp.com/cable"
```

(i set both action cable and web socket just to test which worked, no matter which i go with i still get the error)

/config/initializers/redis.rb

```
  require "redis"

    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
    $redis = Redis.new(
                :url => ENV["REDIS_URL"],
              )
```

I dont know what is going on. Is it some kind of default that makes Redis look for local host 6379? I follow the steps step by step and I keep getting this error.

Comment: I configured ActionCable, based on this article you should configure redis or action cable for pruduction environment. https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable#deploying-our-application-to-heroku

Comment: I did follow these steps. Cable.yaml and production.rb are where I configure for production as shown above. Still getting this error though. I've been trying to solve it for so long.

Comment: Instead of spamming the internets, try one channel. Wait for an answer, and if you don't get one try another approach.

Comment: This question's only been asked 2 places and of course the problem is being debugged while awaiting an answer. Please post relevant to the question's solution.

Answer (score 0):

It started working again. There was an add-on gem in the rails app that was not fully configured. After finishing the setup for the side gem it started working again.

Comment: yes. Do you mean that you need to install the redis add on? because this was included in the documentation that I attached

Comment: no i am working with the gem anycable and i just needed to finish installing it properly as it interacts with redis.